# safari 5 toolbar separator/flexiblespace/spacer not showing anymore

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, safari

anyone know why my separator/flexiblespace/spacer aren't showing on safari 5?
do you know if there is a away to add 'em back (maybe with the plist file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Apple decided (for some ridiculous reason) not to include them in the customization pane anymore! It's actually easy to add them manually, though:

1. Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist`.
2. Find the key `NSToolbar Configuration BrowserWindowToolbarIdentifier`.
3. Inside that key, find `TB Item Identifiers`. This is a list of the items in your toolbar.
4. Change the strings as you wish. The names of the three missing items are, respectively, `NSToolbarSeparatorItem`, `NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItem`, and `NSToolbarSpaceItem`.

Once you've added the items, you'll even be able to drag them around when customizing your toolbar in Safari!

(This process is made a bit easier by the "Property List Editor" app included with Apple's Developer Tools. And, as always, don't forget to backup the .plist file before making any changes.)